# 2015 MacBook Air stuck in reboot loop during Mojave > Catalina upgrade – any way to view logs/errors?

Tags: catalina, mojave, startup

I'm trying to update my 2015 11" MBA from Mojave (latest patches) to Catalina (newest version of installer). I have >20GB free disk space and I'm running the installer from a USB stick created using the official utility in the Catalina installer package. I have also reset the PRAM/NVRAM recently and run a disk check.

The installer gets to the black-screen, Apple-logo stage and after a while says "Estimating time remaining" but the progress bar never advances beyond about 30% (near the "n" in "Estimating). After a few hours (not sure of an exact time) the machine will reboot and the same progress bar will appear and start to fill again. But it never advances beyond that position or completes.

Most recently, I've left the installation for **8 days** to no avail. Before that I was able to abandon the installation and use Recovery Mode to restore Mojave, exactly as I'd left it, and retry the installation from there.

Is there anything I should try in this situation, and perhaps more importantly, is it possible to view logs from the installation process to try to figure out where it's getting stuck? I've seen `Cmd+L` mentioned in a few places but hitting this at the black-screen stage does nothing.

If needs be I can just restore Mojave again and continue using that, but my other machine is running Catalina and I'd like them to be running matching versions if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you update directly without a USB installer? 8 days is way too long, a couple hours should do it at most.

Comment: I originally wanted to install from USB to avoid using up space on the main disk, but I should have freed enough to try running the installer directly. I'll restore to Mojave, restart the update and get back to you.

Comment: No dice I'm afraid; restored to Mojave, downloaded the Catalina installer from the App Store, but it quickly reaches the same point ("Estimated time remaining" with the progress bar about 40% full) and remains there, rebooting every couple of hours only to return to that point. 72 hrs now – anything else I can try, or logs I might be able to view?

Comment: Keep a close eye on your install and make sure you boot into verbose mode (CMD + V) every time the machine reboots. I haven’t tried this in a long time but I believe that you’ll see additional installer console text during the process. Take a photo when it’s stalled.

Comment: @pion Thanks – I enabled verbose boot, but unfortunately the installer itself doesn't respect this and I haven't been able to get more information to display, even by switching to the "classic" install UI (Shift+Ctrl+Opt+Cmd+W). There is supposedly a shortcut to display a terminal/log but I couldn't get it to work. I've seen a hint about disabling third-party kexts (if I even have any) so am currently restoring to Mojave once again to try this.